# Python PyCrypto and RSA problem

Tags: python, rsa, pycrypto

I'e got simple RSA python script:

```
import Crypto.PublicKey.RSA
import rsakey
from Crypto.PublicKey import pubkey

# Some global stuff
impl = Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.RSAImplementation(use_fast_math = True)
RSAObj = impl.construct(rsakey.RSAKeys)

def decrypt(encrypted):
        return RSAObj.decrypt(encrypted)
```

and when I try to run it my CLI shows error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "otrsa.py", line 6, in 
>       impl = Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.RSAImplementation(use_fast_math
>   = True) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute
>   'RSAImplementation'

I'm really new to Python and I don't know what it means.
I would be thankful for any kind of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crypto.PublicKey.RSA contains a class called RSAImplementation (see http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/apidoc/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.RSAImplementation-class.html).

The following works for me (in Python 2.7.1 on 32-bit Windows):

```
import Crypto.PublicKey.RSA
impl = Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.RSAImplementation()
```

Note that, by default, fast math will be used if it is available. Forcing use_fast_math just causes a runtime error if it is not available.

Comment: I know it's not clear from PyCrypto's all-too-sparse documentation, but RSAImplementation is an internal API that might change in the future.  The only reason it exists is so that the SelfTest modules could test the non-fastmath code alongside the fastmath code.

Please file a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/pycrypto/+bugs if you find that you can't use the usual RSA.construct, RSA.generate, etc methods.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I get the same error -- perhaps some miss-match between the docs and code?

What little I've used pyCrypto, I've found M2Crypto to be a better library overall -- you might want to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

It means that Crypto.PublicKey.RSA does not have the function/variable called 'RSAImplementation"

Comment: It means he is somehow not importing the module properly, because the pycrypto module most certainly does have a Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.RSAImplementation class.